# Win 11 home ed. with Admin privs. Can not run "Phone Link" despite multiple uninstall/reinstall reboots. There is no executable to run

Tags: permissions, windows-11, links, phone

I am the computer's owner with Administrator privileges, on Windows 11 Home Ed., but can not run "Phone Link" because "the app has been blocked by your system administrator" I suspect that this is because I would need to be at the "TrustedInstaller" level to run it. I have tried running as Administrator, uninstalled and re-installed "Phone Link," done multiple re-boots, etc, and tried PowerRun, but it will not run even far enough to get to the BarCode screen. Any idea how I can solve this? "Phone Link" AKA "Link for Windows" has no executable file, and a shortcut cannot be created, nor can it be dragged onto PowerRun.

Comment: Have you tried this regedit edit? https://technoresult.com/100-worked-fix-this-app-has-been-blocked-by-your-system-administrator/#Solution_4_Disable_User_Account_Control_settings_using_Registry_Editor

Comment: Phone Link is intended to be run by the user, it has absolutely nothing to do with TrustedInstaller. Phone Link is part of Windows, but is your Windows fully updated? Please add details including screenshot on the error you're getting when running Phone Link. Also try [this advice](https://www.makeuseof.com/app-blocked-by-system-administrator-windows/).